Dart_Comparing entered password with the correct one -> "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'"
I cannot understand how this does not work.
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  AskPassword ("dog");
}  
AskPassword (correct){
  while (true){
    print("Write password.");
    var password = stdin.readLineSync();
    if (password = correct){
      print("Thank you!");
    } else {
    continue;
    }
  }
}

I have tried with removing "" and adding str and such but it does not work.

When doing equability check in Dart (and most programming language) you use the == when you want to compare if two objects are representing the same value.
You have used = which means "assignment" and are used to assign a value to a given variable.
So the correct code would be:
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  askPassword("dog");
}

void askPassword(String correct) {
  while (true) {
    print("Write password.");
    var password = stdin.readLineSync();
    if (password == correct) {
      print("Thank you!");
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
}

I have also done some other improvements:

If a method are not suppose to return anything, you should specify void since otherwise, Dart assume you want dynamic which means the method can return anything and/or nothing.

Name of methods should start with lowercase letter since we only use starting uppercase letters for types in Dart. There are lot of important reasons for following naming conventions in programming languages but the most important one is readability.

Parameters should have types since default are, again, dynamic which can mean any type of value. But your code expect a String object so your method should specify that.


